# Ionic Unexpected key "NSMainNibFile~ipad" while parsing <dict/>

Tags: xcode, npm, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am having an issue while using `add platform ios` command to build ios app in ionic project. The project builds successfully in android but not is IOS.

Command used:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Error:

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.4
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: ../../documents/a-copy/platforms/ios
    Package: com.qodelogix.assurant
    Name: Assurant Drive
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.5.5
Installing "cordova-android-support-gradle-release" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-braintree" for ios
Embedded Frameworks in cordova-plugin-braintree
Added Arch stripping run script build phase
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for ios
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-camera': Error: Unexpected key "NSMainNibFile~ipad" while parsing <dict/>.
```

Ionic Info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.5.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : browser 5.0.3
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.0, (and 12 other plugins)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 5.1.0
   NodeJS     : v8.11.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.4.1
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

Please help me fix this error. Any help is appreciated.